# iPhone Twitter Timeline With User Name

Tags: iphone, twitter, timeline

today i managed to incorporate a users timeline into my iphone app, unfortunately all i can see is the status' of other users without any screen name identification.

anyone know how to display the username as a title to a cell in a UITableView? i.e how to call the information from twitter to put in there

thanks in advance

mike

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa             in the comment i read Stanleys comment and found what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GET statuses/friends_timeline` API call as described by the official Twitter API documentation.

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/friends_timeline

Comment: i started learning coding 4wks ago ao please bear with me, i've read that but am still confused. how would that be used along side https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone ??

Comment: this is the API that i call, but i dont know how to pull the username out and into the table. i thought if the info was there it would show.

Comment: its probably worth looking at MGTwitterEngine which may help you

Comment: I have MGTwitterEngine which is getting the updates for my timeline, I just need to know how to display the screenNames along with the status'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to  create a custom subclass of UITableCellView where you layout things like the title, content, icon etc. You can layout your custom view in the interface builder and set a label at the top of the Cell that you programatically fill with the user name as the Cell becomes visible.

Comment: thanks but i need to know how to get the username from twitter before i can do any of that, thanks for the reply tho